# Generating a file with a particular CRC value

Tags: crc

I have no idea where to start and even all mighty Google didn't find an answer.

Any web application or C#\Python\C\C++ would be grate as well.
Thanks.

Comment: Software recommendation => off-topic.

Comment: "as well". I meant that I need help doing that. If you also happen to know any program that already do so please direct me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[My spoof.c code](https://github.com/madler/spoof) tells you how to modify a file to get the desired CRC.